# Dynamicall updating rules at run-time

Tags: antlr, antlr3

When sending an AT command it is normally terminated by \r\n, but, in fact,  these are really two 'register variables' S3 and S4.

By default S3=='\r' and S4=='\n', but the user can change these at runtime with the command ATSx=

How can I handle this in my Antlr lexer/parser?

Each command has the form AT[parameters]S3S4, how can I handle that if the user changes the value of S3 or S4?

Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Does no one know? Heeeeelp !!!!  Please ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such option to dynamically change lexer- or parser-rules AFAIK. Of course, there are work-arounds possible like re-creating the lexer/parser upon changing register variables', but it won't be pretty, I guess...

---

**Edit**

> ***mawg wrote***
>
> *re-creating the lexr & poarser (well, lexer only, I guess) - could you leaborate on that?*

Rewriting the original grammar file (only the lexer rules, as you correctly mention) and recompiling it on the fly. See: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

Comment: re-creating the lexr & poarser (well, lexer only, I guess) - could you leaborate on that?

Comment: I am parsing the Hayes modem AT command set. AT commands are well defined and I can cover them completely with lexer/parser rules.

As I said, each line generally ends with \r\n, but these are in registers S3 & S4 which the user can change. I have never seen anything except 'blank' and \n, but theorectically they could be anything at all...